# getting started creating a  webservice with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I want to create a webservice in the c#.net.

How do I create a Web Service that I could use with a winforms app to communicate over a network.

Could someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: It's not a web service if it's not available on the web..

Comment: @Prisoner - We have plenty of web services running on web servers on our *intranet*.

Comment: Yes, ok you're right.. You can have web services that aren't available on the "web" but the way I read the OPs question I got the impression that he's not really looking for a web service.

Comment: i want to create a webservice , can u help me?

Comment: @priyanka Windows forms have nothing to do with web services. You should always search for some tutorial on the net for `How do I questions?` and then if you are stuck or confused while reading the tutorial, feel free to ask questions. See you got a down vote (I'm not the one who down voted you) and your question is likely to get closed. You're a programmer and you should put a practice of self learning. I'm not lecturing you here but self learning would be beneficial for your future. Any ways I have found a tutorial for you http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx

Comment: @priyanka when you say web service and communicate between two computers over a network it can get confusing since they can be two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: I missed your bit about windows forms. When you say web service you mean some something that exposes data over an intranet or the internet. I'm sure that is what you meant. Communicating between two applications (like a **chat** application) **could** use a webservice to communicate OR could communicate directly to each other over the network. I think I'm sure this is NOT what you meant.

You have some reading to do. Read [this for some of the jargon on web services](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Building-XML-Web-Services-Using-C-sharp-and-ASP.NET/1/).

You have mainly two options with web services:

1. XML Web Services (.asmx) : This is basically outdated. But its a little simpler IMO so just try it out. Here is a basic [sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hs6sw69%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
2. [Windows Communication Foundation(WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) : This (again IMO) is a slightly more complex option. Its an entire framework for building Service Oriented Applications.  See this blog article series on [getting started with WCF.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx)

Another thing you should learn about once you're done with WCF is Rest.
See [How I explained REST to my wife](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284).

You can [use WCF to build RESTful web services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/04/03/creating-restful-services-using-wcf.aspx), which is what things are moving to today.

And one of the best addon features of WCF is [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106). Which allows you to expose your database (With [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723)) over a web service, and your clients can run Linq queries on this service.

You do have a lot of reading to do. Start off by getting a good C# 4 book or a beginners WCF book. (**Search** Stackoverflow for book recommendations, There are tons.)

Once you hit a specific problem then you can come here, **search** for an answer. If it doesn't exist, post it as a question.

Good Luck.